# Detecting polygon self-intersection

Tags: openlayers, turf

Currently using OpenLayers to allow users to zoom/pan to an area and drop a modifiable 1x1KM Square Polygon. As this polygon is modifiable, for the purposes of validation I need to ensure the final "saved" polygon does not have any crossed lines or does not self-intersect. Some research into this has yielded that both the JSTS and TurfJS libraries are capable of checking a status of a polygon. However I have been unsuccessful thus far as the kinks method (TurfJS) returns an e.forEach error when passing the newly passed feature to turf.

```
x=vectorLayer.getSource().getFeatures();
kinkedPoly=turf.polygon(x[0]);
unkinkedPoly=turf.kinks(kinkedPoly);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5m2ec1yq/1/

Comment: Please include a code snippet and the exach error in context within the body of the question. Folks are more likely to review code than follow a link, and links tend to fail over time, which would render the question damaged or useless.

Comment: Apologies, i've appended code into the post now, unsure if this makes a difference as the post looks like it's been closed but it's been amended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is wrong here is that you are giving features object to `turf.polygon()` function. It needs polygon coordinates, so it should be something like this:

```
  layerSource=vectorLayer.getSource();
  layerSource.forEachFeature(function(feature) {
    var polygon = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
    kinkedPoly=turf.polygon(polygon);
    unkinkedPoly=turf.kinks(kinkedPoly);
  });
```

Comment: Accepted answer, I didn't realise I had to pass the co-ordinates of the Polygon, thank you for the quick response!