# Detecting self-intersecting polygons in OpenLayers

Tags: polygon, javascript, openlayers

I am using OpenLayers Version: 6.3.1. I am allowing users to draw a Polygon in my website. I want to validate the polygon by checking for self intersection. Like This:

[image: This is a **Single** Polygon]

I referred to [Detecting polygon self-intersection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311628/detecting-polygon-self-intersection) and proceeded with using turf.

```
 draw.on('drawend', function(){
      var layerSource = vector.getSource();
      layerSource.forEachFeature(function(feature){
        var poly = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
        var kinkedPoly=turf.polygon(poly);
        console.log('kinkedpoly='+kinkedPoly);
        var unkinkedPoly=turf.kinks(kinkedPoly);
        console.log('UnkinkedPoly=' + unkinkedPoly);
      });
});
```

I don't know how to proceed further. What should I change? Can someone suggest any other method?

Comment: It's not clear why you are not satisfied `turf.kinks` method. Please edit your question and explain it in more details. But one thing is definitely true: `turf.js` works with unprojected `EPSG:4326` coordinates. Your view CRS is most probably projected, so you have first to convert drawn object geometry CRS to `EPSG:4326`.

Comment: `turf.kinks` returns a feature collection containing all points where self-intersection is found. So if you just want to validate the presence or absence of *any* self-intersection, you can check the length of the returned feature collection's `features` array. What happens then is up to your application (e.g. throw an error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use turf's unkinkPolygon method which returns a collection of polygons if the input polygon is kinked.  Use the coordinates of those polygons to convert the drawn feature's geometry to a MultiPolygon of unkinked polygons.

```
draw.on('drawend', function(event) {
  var feature = event.feature;
  if (feature.getGeometry().getType() === "Polygon") {
    var poly = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
    var kinkedPoly = turf.polygon(poly);
    var unkinkedPoly = turf.unkinkPolygon(kinkedPoly);
    if (unkinkedPoly.features.length > 1) {
      var coordinates = [];
      unkinkedPoly.features.forEach(function(feature) {
        coordinates.push(feature.geometry.coordinates);
      });
      console.log(JSON.stringify(coordinates));
      feature.setGeometry(new MultiPolygon(coordinates));
    }
  }
});
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/draw-features-4tcrh

Comment: Does this mean that with these `turf` methods it's essentially irrelevant what CRS the geometry is in?

Comment: Some turf methods only work with LonLat, for example any method which involves distance, tolerance, buffer, etc.  There seems to be no problem with projection where the only values needed are coordinates.

Comment: Good to know to avoid unnecessary transforms. Although I admit I would still prefer to work with EPSG:4326, since one can never know what's behind the scene. What about intersect? Would I get the same geometry with projected and lon,lat coordinates?

Comment: Transforming a polygon to EPSG:4326, dekinking it then transforming it back would give a different results as the shapes would change and lines intersect at a different point.  If unsure of turf's behaviour it would be better to scale down so all coordinates between -90 and +90, do the turf calculations then scale back up.